# Software to accurately identify unknown songs without words?

Tags: music-recognition

I've been trying for a *long* time to identify the name of the piece being played in the background during this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SpkyGo_OQU

I tried Shazam with no success - it directed me to some hoedown song that does not even sound remotely like this. There are no words so I can't look it up using lyrics like I usually do.

Does software exist that identify songs without words?

Comment: Isn't a song without word a tune?

Comment: Well music recognition software like Jaikoz doesn't use lyrics to guess the song.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am unsure if this is good enough...*

The service [mooma.sh](http://www.mooma.sh) gave me the following result: [Craig Riley - Hangin' Out](https://open.spotify.com/track/5jIbjX8MWHXfKkVvNo7zAD) (alongside another useless result).

Craig Riley - Hangin' Out sounds very similar to the song on the video. I had to listen multiple times to make sure I was not listening to the same song.

I believe in Craig Riley - Hangin' Out the melody uses strings instrument (mandolin or guitar) while the melody on video sounds more like piano. In addition, the melody does not match, but it has similar structure (see notes) and the same tempo. The percussion sound identical.

---

Notes:

Listening to the music in the other videos on the channel you can notice that you never hear the song properly die, it just fades off at the end of the video, regardless of the lenght of the video. I conjecture they are looping a section of the song. *Although I have not done a proper analysis of this, which is off-topic on this site anyway.*

I speculate that the songs could be reinterpretation of the same original, or perhaps they are improvisations to a generic percussion track or samples. *However, that's just my opinion.*

Comment: I tried to use mooma.sh to extract the name of the song used in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7Qge1QbcaE it renders and displays nothing, then "Sorry, this video cannot be analysed by MooMash."

Comment: @InterLinked I do not know why. This is an educated guess: mooma needs the video converted to audio only webm by YouTube. I had a look at the formats that YouTube has converted the video you link, the one in the question and few others that work. YouTube has converted every video I tested to that format except the one you link. YouTube takes time to do these conversions, and popular videos get priority. If that is the problem, it probably will work eventually. Although note I only tested a small sample. I will see if I can contact mooma, although I do not expect a reply.

Comment: Also, this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_zTdBVUuYM&list=PLX0GBEHa4qdp_bxU13RzSHcySVKhG4Unt&index=1 - contains the same song and yet the service incorrectly identified it. I've heard the tune is relatively common however.

Comment: @InterLinked I tried other software (Midomi, Tunatic, Audiggle, etc...) on that one, but could not get a good identification. Being it common, it could be on public domain or on an attribution free license. It could even be [made to mimic something else](https://youtu.be/7vfqkvwW2fs?t=5m53s). I had a look at the [Youtube Audio Gallery](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3376882?hl=en) but couldn't find it. Consider asking Mike Mueller about the Girls Soccer video, he published an email on the channel, being recent he might remember. *Btw, that music reminds of The Sim*.

Comment: @InterLinked The same happens to me. “Sorry, this video cannot be analysed by MooMash.”.